# Writing the result of a pymssql query in a seperate list

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I am reading data from a database table with pymssql.
The column I am selecting contains 11 rows.

This is the code I am using:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT SL FROM SLM')
text = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall()]
```

However this code writes the result of the query in one list.

Is it possible to select every row seperately and write the result in 11 seperate lists?

Comment: so instead of a list you want to have a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a tuple of tuples. So, *if* it's a list of *lists* you want, you need to convert each row tuples to a list:

```
text = [list(r) for r in cursor.fetchall()]
```

If you don't mind having a list of tuples, then:

```
text = [r for r in cursor.fetchall()]
```

And, of course, if you don't mind having a tuple of tuples:

```
text = cursor.fetchall()
```

If I have misunderstood what you are looking for, please clarify.